# If date field is blank return blank but if it has a date return the day in week

Tags: date

I have am using this formula which returns the correct day of the week based on date in cells A2:A

=ArrayFormula(switch(WEEKDAY(A3),"","",1,"Sunday",2,"Monday",3,"Tuesday",4,"Wednesday",5, "Thursday",6,"Friday",7,"Saturday"))

I also need it to include if cell A3 is blank "" then return blank "".

I thought this part ,"","" would do as I require, however it simply returns the exact same result had I not included this part!

how can I include the isblank formula here?

An example sheet is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15_PYwwUR6K9s3Jl6eEoH06E_S_8H21HZJFbkqP-HPVY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it :)

```
=IF(P3="","",(switch(WEEKDAY(P3),1,"Sunday",2,"Monday",3,"Tuesday",4,"Wednesday",5, "Thursday",6,"Friday",7,"Saturday")))
```